# IllegalArgumentException.class as expected in JUnit

Tags: java, class, junit

Let's say I have this simple method I want to unit test:

```
public class Add {
    public static int addTheFollowingPositiveNumberToOne(int a) {
        if(a <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        int b = 1 + a;
        return b;
    }
}
```

I want to make sure IllegalArgumentException is thrown if the parameter is less than or equal to 0.

The JUnit code would look something like this:

```
@Test (expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testIllegalArgumentException() {
    int a = -1;
    Add.addTheFollowingPositiveNumberToOne(a);
}
```

Why do I have to add .class at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see the API document of [expected() parameter](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html#expected%28%29), it takes parameter of type `Class`. That's why you are passing `IllegalArgumentException` class type as `IllegalArgumentException.class`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `IllegalArgumentException` is a class that is **thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.** This is actually a class in java that extends `RuntimeException`. This is the inheritance hierarchy.

```
java.lang.Object
--java.lang.Throwable
   --java.lang.Exception
      --java.lang.RuntimeException
        --java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

As for why you need to specify the `@Test (expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)`, here is a simple explanation:

The `@Test` annotation **supports two optional parameters**. **The first**, expected, **declares that a test method should throw an exception**. **If it doesn't throw an exception or if it throws a different exception than the one declared, the test fails**. For example, the **following test succeeds**:

```
@Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class) public void outOfBounds() {
       new ArrayList<Object>().get(1);
    }
```

The **second optional parameter, timeout, causes a test to fail if it takes longer than a specified amount of clock time (measured in milliseconds)**. The following test fails:

```
@Test(timeout=100) public void infinity() {
   while(true);
}
```

For reference check:

- [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)
- [JUnit API](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html)

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you write `.class` after a class name, it references the [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object that represents the given class.

Also, another important thing to note is that

You use the `ClassName.class` when an instance of that class is not available. And you use `classObject.getClass()` when an instance of the class available.

If you look at the [docs](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html#expected%28%29) of `expected()` of the `@Test` annotation,

*public abstract java.lang.Class expected*

> Optionally specify expected, a Throwable, to cause a test method to succeed iff an exception of the specified class is thrown by the method.

`expected` takes the parameter of type `class`(which extends `Throwable`) and thus you give `.class` after the `IllegalArgumentException`.

`IllegalArgumentException` - extends throwable
`.class` - gives the class object which is expected.

Comment: That explains it. Thanks!